# Error: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, router

I was trying to learn angular. But I am getting some issue.

In it, I am using lazy loading module base. I create a admin module and also call it in app.module. I also add commonModule in admin.module.ts and BrowserModule in app.ts.

On adding the array, I getting the issue.

```
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Here is the screenshot of `error`

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is  `admin.module`

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';

import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component'; 
import { AdminHeaderComponent } from '../shared/admin-header/admin-header.component';
import {AdminSidebarComponent } from '../shared/admin-sidebar/admin-sidebar.component';

import {galleryService} from '../services/gallery.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      AdminRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [ 
      AdminComponent, 
      AdminHeaderComponent,
      AdminSidebarComponent
    ],
  
     providers: [
       galleryService
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }



App.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {AdminModule} from './admin/admin.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './general/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './general/register/register.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { AuthGuard } from'./general/auth.guard'
import { SecurityService } from './services/security.service';
import { ErrorService } from './services/error.service';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {JwtInterceptor, ErrorInterceptor} from './_helper';

// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helper';
import { CardComponent } from './shared/card/card.component'; 


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    CardComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
      AdminModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule, // required animations module
      ToastrModule.forRoot() // ToastrModule added
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, SecurityService, fakeBackendProvider,
      {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true
      },
      {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true
      }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of gallerylist">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h4 class="card-title card-header-primary">Simple Table</h4>
                  <p class="card-category"> Here is a subtitle for this table</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>

list.component.ts


getGallery(){
    this.gallery.getAllGallery().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.gallerylist = data;
        console.log(this.gallerylist);
    })
  }
```

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I also studied the previous articles but I did not getting solution. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your HTML? the one that is responsible for this error

Comment: And not as a screenshot please

Comment: What data does gallerylist has?

Comment: i fetch data from api and put it in any array. Here is the data. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Comment: You are calling this api in ngOnInit() ?

Comment: I follow it. Please have a look https://github.com/RameshMF/Angular9-SpringBoot-CRUD-Tutorial/blob/master/angular9-springboot-client/src/app/employee-list/employee-list.component.ts

Comment: not  a joke. have you tried to turn it off and on again? the ng serve I mean. I had weird issues like that before

Comment: Yes.. i just restart the command ng serve but it is giving same issue.

Comment: also. your galarylist type shouldnt be of type Observable<Gallary>. because you are only assigning data to it once its there. so it should be of type  Gallary[]. try that

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: try a very simple ngfor in another component and see if that works. if it doesn't then something is fishy in the background. don't use an API just a simple hardcoded list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217211/discussion-between-mj-jameel-and-vick-sain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking everthing and its goes fine. Than you have to check `angular.json` file.

May be you added any jquery script which create any element through script.

I fix it by removing the unwanted script from angular.json.

Thanks